# I want to make sure function comes after loading of external HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make sure the alert comes after the loading of the external HTML?

```
function changeContent(){
  $('#contentmain').load("contentmain.html", function(){
    alert("something");
}
)}
```

I've been playing around with $(document).ready, but no luck so far.

Many thanks!

Update:

The result of this code is that it depends (on what, I don't know): sometimes the alert comes first, sometimes it comes second...

Comment: Your current code should do just fine.

Comment: So do you have a problem with your current code? It should work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is right.

From the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
Callback Function

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.
```

Answer (score 0):

are you loading iFrames?

try the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$('#iframeID').load(function(){
    // I am totally loaded and lets begin the hunt now.
});
```

Alternatively, If you are loading content via ajax, you can use [.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    // ajax call has completed and lets begin the hunt now.
});
```